# ContextMenu for children in ExpandableListAdapter

Tags: android, contextmenu, parent-child, expandablelistview, children

I'm trying to create a `ContextMenu` if the user long clicks on an item (group or group child) for an `ExpandableListAdater` but the `ContextMenu` only shows for long clicks on group items and not for group child items:

onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    registerForContextMenu(getExpandableListView());
```

onCreateContextMenu:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    Log.i("", "Click");
    ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo info = (ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;

    int type = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(info.packedPosition);
    int groupPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(info.packedPosition);
    int childPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(info.packedPosition);

    // Show context menu for groups
    if (type == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_GROUP) {
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Group");
        menu.add(0, 0, 1, "Delete");

        // Show context menu for children
    } else if (type == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Child");
        menu.add(0, 0, 1, "Delete");
    }
}
```

onContextItemSelected:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo info = (ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) item
            .getMenuInfo();

    int type = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(info.packedPosition);
    int groupPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(info.packedPosition);
    int childPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(info.packedPosition);

    if (type == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_GROUP) {
        // do something with parent

    } else if (type == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {
        // do someting with child
    }

    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

I think I'm missing someting because "Click" isn't logged if I long click on a child. I think that `onCreateContextMenu` isn't invoked if I long click on a child. How do I manage to show a `ContextMenu` for `ExpandableListAdapter` group children?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is:

```
@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // Check your child items here
    return true;
}
```

Auto-implementation was `return false;`